# Make all numbers in array Absolute value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, absolute-value

I'm trying to make all values in the below array absolute, after trying several methods the results that appears is 5 the first element in the array. the below is the code given:

```
describe('absoluteValueArray', () => {
    it('Gets multiple absolute values', () => {
      const result = absoluteValueArray([-5,-50,-25,-568])
      expect(result).toEqual([5,50,25,568])
    })
  })
```

Function I tried is the below:

```
const absoluteValueArray = (array) => {

    var index, len;
    var array = ["-5", "-50", "-25" , "-568"];
    for (index = 0, len = array.length; index < len; ++index) {
      let res = Math.abs(array[index]);
      return res;
    }

}
```

Comment: please add at least one try.

Comment: _"after trying several methods the results that appears is somethimes NaN"_ - None of them are in your "question" -> [mcve]

Comment: Part of the [mre] is the *output* - in this case presumably the test is failing because the output is just `5`, which should give you a clue about what the problem is, but please include it in the question.

Comment: done, I edited my post.

Comment: After having added one of the several attempts: what have you tried to check **why** this does not worko? As a hint: why did you put a `return` statement in the `for` loop?

Comment: @NicoHaase You can't expect OP to have that knowledge, nor does it add any value to the question. Please note that "Not enough effort" is not a close reason, as has been discussed on Meta _many_ times before. ([1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260828/479156), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253069/479156), [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253137/479156), [4](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270903/479156), [5](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251775/479156))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You approach does not work in this line and the next

```
let res = Math.abs(array[index]);
return res;
```

because you need to assign the absolute value to the array or a new array at the same index, like

```
resultArray[i] = Math.abs(array[index]);
```

and return the array **after** finishing the loop.

The original return inside of the loop exits the loop with the first element.

---

Instead, you could take [`Math.abs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs) as callback for [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
const absoluteValueArray = (array) => {
    return array.map(Math.abs);
}

console.log(absoluteValueArray([-5, -50, -25, -568]));
```